# Count how many lines are in a QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit

I'm trying to setup a program which will count how many lines are in a QTextEdit and run a for loop for the amount of lines have been counted. How could I go about doing this?

Comment: Should empty lines be counted as well?. It would also be great to show what you have tried

Comment: Yes, I want all lines to the end of the QTextEdit to be counted

Comment: Please add the code you have tried. Just a minimal example not your whole program.

Comment: QTextEdit.document().lineCount()

Answer (score 2):

```
ui->plainTextEdit->document()->blockCount()
```

> QTextDocument *QPlainTextEdit::document() const

Returns a pointer to the underlying document.

> blockCount : const int

Returns the number of text blocks in the document.

The value of this property is undefined in documents with tables or frames.

By default, if defined, this property contains a value of 1.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#document

Comment: will this be equivalent to counting the `carriage return`?